# google-apps-script: No "source" field on event trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I've set up a trigger for submission of a Google form to run one of my Google scripts:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmitted')
    .forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
```

My `onFormSubmitted` function gets triggered, but the event argument supplied to the function has no `source` attribute. It has 3 of the 4 fields that [the documentation says it should have](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4).

So how should I get a reference to the form that triggered this event?

**TMI**

```
function onFormSubmitted(data, arg) {
  log(8, data['triggerUid'], -1) // => 1874727473075378640
  log(9, data['authMode'], -1) // => FULL
  log(10, data['response'], -1) // => FormResponse
  log(11, data['source'], -1) // => undefined
}
```

Comment: Show the `onFormSubmitted` function code and the exact error.

Comment: If the apps script file is bound to the Form, then you can get the active Form. `var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();`  This works for a stand alone file installed as an add-on also.  A stand alone file that is not used as an add-on wouldn't be able to trigger the On Form Submit event.  I'm not sure about a library.  But unless you are using the apps script file as a library, I'd try to get the active Form.

Comment: @SandyGood : hm... I'm using this script to create lots of forms and register a trigger. Is it possible that a script can be bound to multiple forms?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about it not being able to be triggered in a stand alone file.  So, are you using the same function for multiple Forms?  I didn't know that there can be two args passed to the function for the trigger?  `function onFormSubmitted(data, arg)`  Not that that may have anything to do with your issue.

Comment: @SandyGood : Yes, I am using the same function for multiple forms. (The forms are generated programmatically.) When my `onFormSubmit` function calls `FormApp.getActiveForm()`, I get `undefined`.

Comment: Documentation: `A Form object, representing the Google Forms file to which the script is` **`bound.`** If script ain't bound, it obviously returns ``undefined``

Comment: @I'-'I : Thanks, but I assumed that binding was automatically performed when any form invoked a script (in order that a single script could serve multiple forms). So it wasn't obvious to me that my script would not be bound at execution time.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound I believe @tehhowch answer satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation for the event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4), if the script is not bound, then there is no associated `source` property. You can overcome this by storing the form id in [properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) using the trigger uid. Then in your form submit code, use the trigger uid to obtain the proper Form.

```
function getFormId_(triggerId) {
  const store = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var formId = store.getProperty(triggerId);
  if (!formId) console.warn("No form ID found for trigger ID '" + triggerId);
  return formId;
}
function createSubmitTrigger_(form, functionName) {
  const formId = form.getId();
  const trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).forForm(form)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();

  const store = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  store.setProperty(trigger.getUniqueId(), formId);
}

function myFormSubmit(e) {
  const form = FormApp.openById(getFormId_(e.triggerUid));
  ...
}
```

It's possible this approach (store & retrieve) can be backwards-applied, though this will depend on how the triggers have previously been configured - you cannot programmatically (or otherwise) interact with others' triggers.

```
function storeAll() { // Run once (more is ok too, will just overwrite existing keys).
  function cb(acc, t, i, allVals) { // callback for Array#reduce
    acc[t.getUniqueId()] = t.getTriggerSourceId();
    return acc;
  }

  const newProps = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().reduce(cb, {});
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(newProps);
}
```

References

- [`Trigger` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger)
- [`getProjectTriggers` is only for current user](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764532)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)